# How to define an empty vector to store 'names' in R?

Tags: r

I want to store names in other vector. So, first I will have to create an empty vector to store these names. 
I know how to define numeric vector. g <- numeric(length=10). But not sure about how to define vector to store names.

Answer (score 5):

Another option :

```
  names_vec  <- vector(mode='character',length=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick:

```
names_vec = character(length = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the number of values in advance, you can start with an empty vector and append to it. This is slow, so don't do it for large quantities of data.

```
names <- c()
for (r in 1:numNames) {
  names <- append(names, "someName")
}
```